# What is an "innovative statement" for faculty application?

Tags: faculty-application

I am putting together a faculty application for a university in Russia.
The University has asked for an "Innovation Statement", along with other documents.

This is the first time I have heard of any such statement. I have googled the term and did not found much information, except one interesting article about "innovation mission statement" which does not fit well with a faculty application.

Any idea what an "innovation statement" is?

Comment: A mis-translation of 'research statement', perhaps?

Comment: Did they ask in English, in Russian, or both?  If they asked in Russian, what was the Russian term they used?  Some of our Russian-speaking members may be able to help.

Comment: No, they ask in English only. 
@avid, no I don't think it is a mistranslation. They have separately asked for a research statement.
Besides, their English website is very professional :D

Answer (score 1):

What makes your research novel, exciting, ground-breaking or significant should be delineated in a innovative statement. How you are advancing your field by eventually accomplishing your aims.